# Problems facing up with in the process of building deep learning development in wsl2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: tensorflow using problem]

I have installed cuda-11.2, cuda-toolkit and cudnn8 in my wsl2 and try to reinstall the whole wsl2 several times but still encounter that problem. I'm quite puzzled. My wsl2's distribution is ubuntu-20.04 and my operating system is Windows11-home.